# PHP - Is plain text http POST to external server secure?

Tags: php, security, post, https

I noticed my bank sends (after a merchant transaction has been initiated and paid) a POST response to my site (http) in plain text. This response contains every parameters of the transaction (card number, signature, etc).

Is this normal ?

I plan to reroute some of the responses to another server with a POST method (bank->server1->server2). Is it considered secured not to encrypt it ?

Comment: Is it going over HTTPS (secure HTTP)? If so, it is not plain text. It is encrypted. POST is used because GET is usually included in plain text in the access logs.

Comment: No it's not, edited.

Comment: Your site do not use https ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the request to your server is not secure (using SSL, HTTPS) it means that anybody in between your server and the sender that is hijacking the connection could read the information. So, in this sense, the answer is no.

Note, however, that the connection between your server and the bank is a lot less prone to hijacking, which usually occurs between your client and the bank. Only people involved in the datacenter your server is in, are on your server, or are somehow on the same connection, are able to plan a (Man-In-The-Middle)-attack.

To elaborate a little bit more: is it normal? Yes, it happens a lot. Is it good? Probably not.

I would definitely secure your connection to your other server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.